# PyCharm Your Terminal Doesn't Support Cursor Position Requests (CPR)

Tags: python, terminal, pycharm

I have the following python code I'm testing out in PyCharm Professional 2021.1.2:

```
from prompt_toolkit import prompt
from prompt_toolkit.history import FileHistory
from prompt_toolkit.auto_suggest import AutoSuggestFromHistory
from prompt_toolkit.completion import WordCompleter
import os

CmdCompleter = WordCompleter(['hello', 'goodnight'])


while 1:
    user_input = prompt('>',
                        history=FileHistory(os.path.expanduser('~/.repl_history')),
                        auto_suggest=AutoSuggestFromHistory(),
                        completer=CmdCompleter)
    print(user_input)
```

PyCharm is running on my Windows host and is configured to use a remote SSH Interpreter on a Debian 10 VM. When I go to run the application, I get `WARNING: your terminal doesn't support cursor position requests (CPR).` within the PyCharm run window. Running the code natively in the Linux VM causes no issues. Is there any configuration, setting, or option I can change to get the output in the PyCharm run window to appear/work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

When testing on PyCharm personally, I got an error:

```
prompt_toolkit.output.win32.NoConsoleScreenBufferError: No Windows console found. Are you running cmd.exe?
```

I don't know why you got a warning but I got an error, but in order to fix this, I just went to Configuration settings and checked `Emulate terminal in output console`:

[image: edit configurations]

[image: emulate terminal in output console]

I hope that this fixes the problem!

Comment: My configuration options look different than this, I think, because I'm using a remote python interpreter in my environment. Under `Execution` options, I only have "Run with Python Console" or "Redirect input from" as options. I don't have the "Emulate terminal in output console" option present

Comment: @fowlball1010 Yep, looks like you can't [`emulate the terminal in output console` when using a remote interpreter](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29204?_ga=2.248406983.1528568398.1623253480-1489396640.1601513300). I don't know if there is any solution to this other than just using your own terminal and to vote for this issue.